# Getting INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed in Firebase PhoneAuth Android even after adding SHA certificates

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed while performing verifyPhoneNumber().
I have successfully entered SHA-1 certificates for release and debug but the problem still persist. Also to cross check that correct certificates were added to firebase, i have verified my apk signature using command line, and they turns out to be exact. Any help will be appreciated. If am missing mentioning something please ask. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as yours.

You need to link the Firebase project with Google Play.

Head to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/you-project-name/settings/accountlinking and on the bottom right click "Link to Google Play"

Comment: i had to begin from scratch as no community member were able to find solution for it. thanks for sending help, may be it will help someone or me even some day.

Comment: It works with a non-published app? I'm trying with an app in alpha stage and I can't..

Comment: I haven't tried myself with an alpha app but I don't see why it shouldn't.

Comment: @AitorAznarÁlvarez describe the problem

Comment: @Ashu My problem was that I did so many tests that I had the Google API for auth plenty of trash. Clean it all and I did auth setup again in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

It works as well as for debug and release builds.
You just need to put the right SHA-1 certificate fingerprints on your application setting page, regenerate a new google-services.json file and replace the old one in your android app :)